# How am I supposed to generate API key for SendGrid through Heroku? Do I use Heroku generated SendGrid Addon credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I recently created my Heroku account and added SendGrid as an add on. However, it does not send me to my SendGrid account when I click the link. Also, I tried to go to SendGrid and use my username and password created by the Heroku add on, but it displays a popup to "Check your *****@heroku.com inbox for an email from us"??

I dont have a heroku email with my account... I am confused, I see that I can't use username or password anymore for the ActionMailer.smtp_settings, but idk how to generate this API key.

Comment: Read the manual. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on

Comment: I followed this, it doesnt take me to the twilio page, i get a 403 error